# I am trying to Post a query to website using ALAMOFIRE and receiving JSON error -1004

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to Post a query to a website using ALAMOFIRE and receiving JSON error -1004. If I use String method no error is received but querying for case is not happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
@IBAction func execute(sender: AnyObject) {

    var wacnumber = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let parameter = ["appReceiptNum":"\(wacnumber)"] as Dictionary
     Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/mycasestatus.do", parameters: parameter, encoding: .JSON)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)
        }
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            print(JSON)
    }

}
```

Comment: "-1004" is kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost. Make sure you can ping host.

Comment: ping fails. Is there anyway to query this website ? Though using response string it provides result of current page and not query result.

Comment: You should refer any developer documentation (if) provided that site.

Comment: im guessing it was something with the simulator?